# how do I write a ref to a component?

Tags: react-native, components

how do I save and write the Ref of the ScrollToFirstErrorHOC component?

```js
export function withScrollToFirstError(Component: t.form.Component): React.ComponentType {
  class ScrollToFirstErrorHOC extends PureComponent<OuterProps & PropsFromState> {
    constructor(props: PropsFromState) {
      super(props);
    }

    public render() {
      return <Component {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollToFirstErrorHOC

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.props.ref(this)
}
```

At parent component

```
<ScrollToFirstErrorHOC ref={_ref => this._scrollRef = _ref} />
```